# A list of strings - determining where I went wrong

Tags: c

This is a part of a problem I need to solve in algorithms and data structure, but I can't get past this point.

The first step is to load a bunch of strings and put them in an array using a double pointer. Seems clear. My initial code was:

```
int main (void){
    char **A, a[50];
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    A=malloc(n*sizeof(a));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
        a[sizeof(a)-1]='\0';
        A[i]=a;
        printf("%s",A[i]);
    }
return 0;

}
```

Since I couldn't find a way to eliminate the first '\n' after entering the number of strings, an example of my input would be:

3Bruce

Jane

Dwayne

The printf function inside the for loop was there to check whether these strings are in their place after I enter them and put them in an array. Seems fine.

However, as soon as I add a simple for loop to check the contents again (before return 0;)

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%s",A[i]);
}
```

Only the last name gets printed three times, meaning others aren't a part of the list (even though it seemed like they were).

I'm wondering if anyone can see where I went wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This is wrong `A=malloc(sizeof(n)*sizeof(a))`, perhaps you meant `A = malloc(n * sizeof(*A))` and always check that `scanf()` succeeded instead of just trusting that `n` has a suitable value.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Still getting the same output though.I checked n, that's not the problem.

Comment: I mean you should ensure that `scanf()` worked, it has nothing to do directly with `n`.  Note that it's still wrong. And `A[i] = a;` means that all the `A` elements point to exactly the same buffer, which is overwritten in every iteration, you have to copy `a`'s content and store a pointer to the copy in `A[i]`. I suggest you read a lot more about how pointers work and what they are.

Comment: Mind to explain why scanf wouldn't work if n turns out to be a correct value after scanning? Thank you, I've been working with pointers for a while now, I clearly missed that. I never would have asked in the first place if I saw pointers for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is a pointer to `char *`, so it have to be allocated to hold `n` pointers:

```
A = malloc(n * sizeof(*A));
```

And after reading from `stdin` you have to remove return to line in this way:

```
a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Then each element from `A` should point to a memory, on which we copy the input:

```
A[i] = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
```

In the end change this assignment `A[i]=a`, which will make all elements of 
`A` point to `a`, to [`strncpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) which will copy `a` string to `A[i]`:

```
strncpy(A[i], a, strlen(a) + 1);
```

---

Other notes, is that `scanf` will leave `\n` in the buffer from which `fgets` is going to read, so you have to consume the `\n` before reading with `fgets`:

```
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
} while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

And don't forget to check the returned value of `scanf` and `fgets` for error cases:

```
if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading n\n");
    return 1;
}
...
if (fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin) != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading input\n");
    return 1;
}
```

In the end don't forget to `free` allocated memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(A[i]);
}
free(A);
```

Comment: `if (fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin) != NULL) {` not only copes with the rare input error (as expressed in the message), but the more common end-of-file.  If looking for error/end-of-file, as good code should, `} while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);` prevents an infinite loop on `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop always stores the input string into the array `a` and stores the same address into each element of `A[i]`.

I have done few corrections to your program:

```
int main (void){
    char **A, a[50];
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    A=malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
       A[i]=malloc(strlen(a)+1);
       strcpy(A[i],a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory once you are done.